# HDD not detected whenever first power on (detected at BIOS level)

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

I am using

> Asus P8H61-M LX Motherboard with latest version of BIOS: 4401
>   One SATA-3 Western Digital Black Series 1.5TB is attached to SATA port 0
>   A Samsung 22x DVDRW SATA drive attached to SATA Port 1.
>   ps/2 Logitech mouse and keyboard.
>   CPU is i3 with DDR3 8Gb RAM.

no other devices are installed.

My problem is that when I turn on the computer, the WD HDD is not detected. ie cannot be booted.
I have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> in order to get it detected.

I'd used the WD data lifeguard software to scan the HDD, the smart status is OK, the surface scan does not show any error at all.

Where did I do wrong? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you enter the BIOS and detect the HDD, does it appear then?

Comment: no, not detected

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the sata port on your motherboard you are connecting the cable to, let me know when you test it please.

[image: Sata Ports]

Comment: Hello...I'm still the same issue after changing from SATA 0 to SATA 2

Comment: If your BIOS supports detection timeout, raise it by a few seconds. it even may happen your hard drive has eminent damage and the diagnosis software is not detecting yet. it may also happen your PSU is on the verge supplying enough energy to your machine.

Comment: also, did you perform any significant change to your hardware?

Comment: no, sad to say that it does not has this feature. My power supply is brand new 850 watts power supply. I'd tried changing the power supply but still getting the same problem. I replaced a different

Comment: no, sad to say that it does not has this feature. My power supply is brand new 850 watts power supply. I'd tried changing the power supply but still getting the same problem. 

I'd replaced a different harddisk and it boots up immediately. I transfer my current WD HDD to other computer, I don't have such problem.

So I am lost now. What could be other issue?

Comment: with all the tests and changes done so far, the only conclusion is that the problem resides on the board itself somehow. have you checked if there are updates for your BIOS?

Comment: bios is most up to date. if it is board problem, why other disk can boot up when turn on?

Comment: bios is most up to date. 

if it is board problem, why other disk can boot up when turn on?

I will try the same HDD again on another same model motherboard to see whether the issue persist.

I will update u with the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It always seemed to me as if the HDD did not receive the wakeup signal for some reason. 
If I remember correctly (it was some time ago) the Mainboard was the issue then.

What you can try:

- Use different Power connector from Power Supply
- Try the HDD in a different computer to cross check reason for behavior.

Otherwise:

- Buy a new one from any online store that allows sending them back without reason. Then at least you'd know if this HDD is the reason.